# How to query/search name of non-friends of a certain user from database?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

I have 2 tables in database: Users and Friend. I want to make a query that searches for users name that are not friends with a certain user using @Query. How should the query look like?

I have created this query for it:

```
@Query("SELECT u.name FROM Users u WHERE u.user_id NOT IN
             (SELECT f.friend_id FROM Friend f WHERE f.user_id= ?1)
        AND u.name LIKE %?2% ", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> searchingNonFriendsByUserId(int userId, String search)
```

But this doesn't give the right results that I want.

Info/attributes about tables:

Users(user_id PK, name, score)

Friend(id PK, user_id, friend_id)

**EXAMPLE FOR CLARIFICATION**:

USERS:
**(1, "test", 5), (2, "Tim", 10), (5, "Tom", 11), (4, "test2", 13), (6, "Tam", 0)**

FRIENDS: **(1, 1, 2) , (2, 1, 5) , (3, 1, 4) , (4, 2, 5) , (5, 2, 1)**

I want names (specified by the LIKE clause) of the users that are not a friend of "Tim" (user_id = 2) for example. Here Tim is friends with "Tom" and "test". For example I type in the letter "T" between the % of the LIKE clause for user_id = 2, Then I want only "Tam" and "test2" to be queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS.

Select the user(s) who are not friends with the given user id by excluding any user who has a row in the `Friend` table where the given user exists (user_id = ?1) or the other way around.

```
SELECT u.name 
FROM Users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Friend
                  WHERE user_id = ?1 AND friend_id = u.user_id)
AND u.user_id != ?1
AND u.name LIKE '%?2%'
```

Comment: Shouldn't be user_id here equal to ?1 instead of friend_id ? Also where is the LIKE clause?

Comment: Can you please clarify what your query does? Because I don't think it does what I want.

Comment: I Updated the question

Comment: Ok I don't want to use the friend_id to fetch non-friends. I want to give the user_id into the query and fetch friend_id from that and then filter the friends of that user to get non-friends names

Comment: Ok so what are the 1's in the query for? Are you only doing it for user_id = 1 here?

Comment: Ok I tried your latest query and it works well! Thanks very much for the help and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out ?

select u.name from Users u where not exists(

Select User_id from friend  where user_id = ?1)